# JQuery Find Table within a Table and selected Radio button

Tags: jquery, radio-button, find, html-table

Table (tbl_outside) has many rows.  In each row is another table (class=tbl_Inside) which contains a radio button group (as shown below).  I need to find the value for the  selected radio for all rows in the table.

This is what I have so far, but I can't seem to find the nested table for each row in tbl_outside.  Hope you can help.

```
$("#tbl_outside > tbody > tr ").each(function() {          
          //find tbl_Inside
          $(this).find("td: > table[class=tbl_Inside]").each(function() {                
                var TRID = $(this).attr("id");
                var theValue = $(this).find("input:radio:checked").val();
                alert(theValue);  
          });        


<table id="tbl_outside">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td> Location </td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="1194">
        <td>
            <table class="tbl_Inside" id="93cf9d8ba8" >
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>
                       <input type="radio" value="h" name="93cf9d8ba8"/>
                  </td>
                  <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>
                       <input type="radio" value="l" name="93cf9d8ba8"/>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                        <input type="radio" value="c" name="93cf9d8ba8"/>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                        <input type="radio" value="r" name="93cf9d8ba8"/>
                  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>
                  <input type="radio" value="f" name="93cf9d8ba8"/>
                  </td>
                  <td></td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
              </table>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="1193">
        <td>
            <table class="tbl_Inside" id="123456" >
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>
                       <input type="radio" value="h" name="123456"/>
                  </td>
                  <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>
                       <input type="radio" value="l" name="123456"/>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                        <input type="radio" value="c" name="123456"/>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                        <input type="radio" value="r" name="123456"/>
                  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>
                  <input type="radio" value="f" name="123456"/>
                  </td>
                  <td></td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
              </table>
         </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: You have a spelling mistake which isn't helping: `tbl_Outside` in your JS but `tbl_outside` in your HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#tbl_outside table.tbl_Inside input:radio:checked').each(function () {
  alert(this.value);
});
```

Comment: Thanks John!  That works great and it's so darn simple!  Thanks Again!